# Do I need to remove programmatically added fragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have programmatically added fragment which is created on activity's **onCreate()** call like this:

```
    mFragment = (MyFragment) pFm.findFragmentByTag(TAG);

    if (mFragment == null) {         
        mFragment = MyFragment.newInstance();
        pFm.beginTransaction().add(mFragment, MyFragment.class.getSimpleName()).commit();
    }
```

The lifetime of fragment is indefinite. The question is, do I have to remove it at some point?, for example at **onDestroy()**, if **isFinishing()** returns **true**?

Comment: why you want to remove it...???

Comment: My intuition tells me that add() calls should often have corresponding remove() calls. However this seems to be not the case.

Comment: @Stipa of course there is a remove being called somewhere at some point. However, if you don't need to explicitly call that yourself for some reason (and not replace ()), then the system takes care of that for you.

Comment: @Stipa: ... and if look at pure layout definitions in XML, you don't even need to use `add()` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to. Adding the Fragment programmatically doesn't make that Fragment different than ones that are added by, say, using the `<fragment>` tag in XML. The Fragment's [lifecycle methods](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) will be called in much the same way as your activity's lifecycle methods are called. They will take care of the Fragment when the application is exiting.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: no, you don't need to remove it. Attached fragments get destroyed when they are detached from the activity or the activity finishes. See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html for more.